# How to deploy the default cubes in dynamics ax 2009?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009

How do we deploy the default cubes in dynamics ax 2009?
what are the steps in deploying the default cubes?
can someone provide a link for the steps?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few seconds of Google turned up the top two links...
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14076

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc590284%28v=ax.50%29.aspx

**EDIT:** If your actual question is regarding errors you have with deploying cubes, then that's because you need to configure them to match your specific environment.

This was a big blunder on Microsoft's part, I think, when they bundled the cubes.  They designed the cubes to work with the DB schema where EVERY license key is on...which no Customer ever has.

So because they did this, that means you have to deploy the cubes and then spend many hours deleting objects and changing things until it matches your environment.

Comment: Yes several times for different clients.  Is your question more about errors you are experiencing when you try and deploy the cubes?  I just edited my answer with some more information.

Comment: I have not tried to deploy the cubes, so I was researching on how to do it. I have read the white paper in the first link you gave, are those the steps to deploy the cubes?

Comment: Yes they are the steps

Comment: Now I understand why the steps include modifying the cubes, thanks to your edited answer. Now it is deploying and there are some errors, I will have to try and fix those.